# apt-get install upgrade does not work on kali linux

Tags: linux, shell

[image]When I try to update, i get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
N: Ignoring file 'getdeb.list.bck' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unable to locate package update
```

my etc/apt/sources.list looks like this:

```
deb http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib

deb-src http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

[image]

Comment: I would reccomend posting this question on https://superuser.com/ . It is somewhat off-topic here, because SO i for programming related questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced such problems a lot. Give it a go. In sources.list file,cut all the repo list and simply add this:-

deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free

and reboot
It works like fun.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! I would suggest you to improve the formatting of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Steps**:

1. Remove the get deb file
2. Run the update command

**Commands**:

```
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list.bck

apt-get update
```